# You see me right now... but you can't

Tags: computer-puzzle

Look over here! Oh... that's right. I'm too small to be seen. But you are still looking at me. Crazy! I know right? Here, how about this? You guess what I am! Okay.

Well if I get too much electricity, good-bye me! Too little, and I can't do anything!

I provide images, text, videos, etc. with my friends (I have so many of them depending on our group size, which...)

Our groups come in a few preset sizes. 1080x720, 480x360, etc.

Finally all coders use me as a basic element for GUI design.

---

Well now. Try to find out what I am...

Comment: the group sizes gave it away... Finding the balance between too broad clues and dead giveaways is not easy! I wish you better luck with that the next time. Upvoted to compensate for the downvotes, as I liked the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you

> A pixel? They are the unit of resolution for most monitors and responsible for rendering images/graphics etc.